# How disable key while specific program is running?

Tags: 14.04, unity, keyboard, wine, playonlinux

When I'm running a game with Play on Linux and I accidentally hit the Super key, it always opens the unity launcher and crashes my game. How can I prevent this, by disabling the super key for this program specifically? I would like to still use the key outside of Play on Linux (although I tried disabling it system-wide and that didn't work either).