# Block Unity keyboard shortcuts when a certain application is active

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, intellij

The great JetBrains IDEs (IDEA et al.) assign pretty much every conceivable keyboard shortcut to some function. While mildly overwhelming at times, it also makes for efficient use.

My problem is that Unity assigns some of these shortcuts as well, and they take precedence. One particularly annoying example is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. The issue has been explored before [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412046/unable-to-use-intellij-idea-keyboard-shortcuts-on-ubuntu).

However, neither of the approaches is satisfactory.

1. Turning off system shortcuts *globally* impedes my overall productivity with the system.
2. Switching to a different keymap in IDEA will confuse the hell out of me when I develop on different platforms (and have to choose different mappings).

Is there a way to turn off system shortcuts only when a certain application is active, i.e. running and in focus?

I'd be willing to run a script every time I launch the application.

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/754884/disable-key-when-program-is-running

Comment: @ByteCommander Looks very relevant, thanks. Do you feel like expanding that into an answer?

Comment: No, I don't think that's worth an answer yet. It looks like that linked answer is only applicable to disabling the [Super] key. I poked the original author of that answer and notified him of your question though, maybe he'll stop by later :)

Answer (score 10):

#### How to automatically disable multiple (specific) shortcuts if (and as long as) a specific application's window is active

The script below will disable specific key shortcuts when an arbitrary application's window is active.

Although you mentioned"*"I'd be willing to run a script every time I launch the application."*, There is no reason to kill the script afterwards, it is extremely low on juice.

#### The script

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import os

app = "gedit"

f = os.path.join(os.environ["HOME"], "keylist")

def run(cmd):
    subprocess.Popen(cmd)

def get(cmd):
    try:
        return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()
    except:
        pass

def getactive():
    return get(["xdotool", "getactivewindow"])

def setkeys(val):
    # --- add the keys to be disabled below  
    keys = [
         ["org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys", "logout"],
         ["org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys", "screensaver"],
        ]
    # ---
    writelist = []
    if not val:
        try:
            values = open(f).read().splitlines()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            values = []
        for i, key in enumerate(keys):
            try:
                cmd = ["gsettings", "set"]+key+[values[i]]
            except IndexError:
                cmd = ["gsettings", "reset"]+key
            run(cmd)
    else:
        for key in keys:
            cmd = ["gsettings", "set"]+key+["['']"]
            read =  get(["gsettings", "get"]+key)
            writelist.append(read)
            run(cmd)

    if writelist:
        open(f, "wt").write("\n".join(writelist))

front1 = None

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    pid = get(["pgrep", app])
    if pid:
        try:
            active = get(["xdotool", "getactivewindow"])
            relevant = get(["xdotool", "search", "--all", "--pid", pid]).splitlines()
            front2 = active in relevant
        except AttributeError:
            front2 = front1           
    else:
        front2 = False
    if front2 != front1:
        if front2:
            setkeys(True)
        else:
            setkeys(False)

    front1 = front2
```

#### How to use

1. The script needs `xdotool`:

   ```bash
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `disable_shortcuts.py`
3. In the head of the script, replace in the line:

   ```python
   app = "gedit"
   ```

   "gedit" by your application, meaning: the process name that owns the window.
4. Test-run the script by the command:

   ```bash
   python3 /path/to/disable_shortcuts.py
   ```
5. If all works fine, add it to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```bash
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && python3 /path/to/disable_shortcuts.py"
   ```

#### Adding more shortcuts to be disabled

As an example, I added the shortcut you mentioned: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. Shortcuts are set in the `dconf` database, and can be set or disabled using `gsettings`.

In the script, these `gsettings` entries are set in the function: `setkeys()`

```python
def setkeys(val):
    # --- add the keys to be disabled below
    keys = [
        ["org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys", "screensaver"]
        ]
    # ---
```

An example to add (disabling) the log out shortcut:

1. Open a terminal window, run the command `dconf watch /`
2. Open System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "System"
3. Re-set the shortcut to itself. In the terminal, you can see the `gsettings` key that belongs to the shortcut:

   [image]
4. Now we have to add the found key (in a slightly different appearance):

   ```
   ["org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys", "logout"]
   ```

   ...to the "keys" list in our function:

   ```python
   def setkeys(val):
       # --- add the keys to be disabled below
       keys = [
           ["org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys", "screensaver"],
            ["org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys", "logout"],
           ]
   ```

Now both <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> are disabled if your application is in front.

#### Explanation

As mentioned, shortcuts, like the ones you mention, are set in the `dconf` database. In the example <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, the key to set or edit the schortcut is:

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screensaver
```

To *disable* the key, the command is:

```bash
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screensaver ""
```

To reset the key to its default value:

```bash
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screensaver
```

The script looks once per second if:

- your application runs at all
- if so, it looks if any of its windows is active
- again (only) if so, it disables the shortcuts, listed in

  ```python
  # --- add the keys to be disabled below
  keys = [
      ["org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys", "screensaver"],
       ["org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys", "logout"],
     ]
  ```

  ...waiting for the next change in state.

If the active window is not one of your application any more, the keys, mentioned in the list, are reset to default.

#### Note

As mentioned earlier, the additional burden to the processor of the script is nihil. You could very well run it on startup, as explained in "How to use".

---

### Affecting multiple applications

As discussed in comments, in OP's specific case, it is useful to apply disabling shortcuts on a *group* of applications, all residing in one directory.

Below a version to apply this on all applications of which the output of

```bash
pgrep -f
```

will include a specific directory. In my example, I set the `/opt` directory, so if the active window is one of any of the applications in `/opt`, the set shortcuts will be disabled.

*bringing a window of one of the applications in /opt to front will disable the logout shortcut*

[image]

*re- enabling the shortcut if another window gets focus*

[image]

#### The script

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import os 

appdir = "/opt"

f = os.path.join(os.environ["HOME"], "keylist")

def run(cmd):
    subprocess.call(cmd)

def get(cmd):
    try:
        return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()
    except:
        pass

def getactive():
    return get(["xdotool", "getactivewindow"])

def setkeys(val):
    # --- add the keys to be disabled below  
    keys = [
         ["org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys", "logout"],
         ["org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys", "screensaver"],
         ["org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings", "begin-move"],
        ]
    # ---
    writelist = []
    if not val:
        try:
            values = open(f).read().splitlines()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            values = []
        # for key in keys:
        for i, key in enumerate(keys):
            try:
                cmd = ["gsettings", "set"]+key+[values[i]]
            except IndexError:
                cmd = ["gsettings", "reset"]+key
            run(cmd)
    else:
        for key in keys:
            cmd = ["gsettings", "set"]+key+["['']"]
            read =  get(["gsettings", "get"]+key)
            writelist.append(read)
            run(cmd)
    if writelist:
        open(f, "wt").write("\n".join(writelist))

front1 = None

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    # check if any of the apps runs at all
    checkpids = get(["pgrep", "-f", appdir])
    # if so:
    if checkpids:
        checkpids = checkpids.splitlines()
        active = getactive()
        # get pid frontmost (doesn't work on pid 0)
        match = [l for l in get(["xprop", "-id", active]).splitlines()\
                 if "_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL)" in l]
        if match:
            # check if pid is of any of the relevant apps
            pid = match[0].split("=")[1].strip()
            front2 = True if pid in checkpids else False
        else:
            front2 = False
    else:
        front2 = False
    if front2 != front1:
        if front2:
            setkeys(True)
        else:
            setkeys(False)
    front1 = front2
```

#### How to use

1. Like the first script, `xdotool` needs to be installed:

   ```bash
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `disable_shortcuts.py`
3. In the head of the script, replace in the line:

   ```python
   appdir = "/opt"
   ```

   "/opt" by the directory your applications are.
4. Test-run the script by the command:

   ```bash
   python3 /path/to/disable_shortcuts.py
   ```
5. If all works fine, add it to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```bash
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && python3 /path/to/disable_shortcuts.py"
   ```

Adding other shortcuts to the list works exactly similar to version 1 of the script.

#### Does it work on all applications?

In your answer, you mention:

> xprop does not reveal PIDs for all windows. Failing example: stopwatch.

Windows with [pid 0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83325/95917) (like tkinter windows, including Idle), have no window- id in the output of `xprop -id`. `Idle` does not have any clashing shortcuts though in my experience. If you run into any application with pid 0 that would require disabling specific shortcuts, please mention.

In that case, a possible escape would be to convert the output of

```
xdotool getactivewindow
```

to hex, the format `wmctrl` uses, and subsequently look up the corresponding `pid` in the output of

```
wmctrl -lp
```

Although that seemed the most obvious thing to do to start with, I didn't use it in the script to keep the script as light-weight as possible.

Comment: @Raphael no, that is not correct. The second one and the first are different, since the first one is made for how you initially asked your question, while the second one is made for additional requirements in the comments. Did you try?

Comment: @Raphael also, a few of your fixes include non desirable use of directly editing dconf. Futhermore, it "fixes" issues you didnt mention in your question. Will comment later. No offense, but imo would be a decent action to accept the (this) answer if it is the basis of your solution.

Comment: @Raphael changing the question after answers were posted, based on the original question is quite, well, not done. In the comment, I already mentioned why editing dconf directly is not the desired way. /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/begin-move is in gsettings (16.04)

Comment: Hi @Raphael, the issue with listed values (as mentioned in the 1st comment) is fixed. Furthermore, the scripts now also adapt user set shortcuts, and resets to them. A backup seems a bit redundant to me, since simply (se) running the script will set all shortcut keys to previously set shortcuts. as explained, using dconf is not desirable and also unnecessary since the fix.

Comment: I finally got around to trying the new version (of the multi-app version). Unfortunately, I'm getting [errors](http://pastebin.com/6dpbn19g).

Comment: @Raphael Thanks for mentioning! I must have mixed up the pasted code somehow, if the settings file does not exist, it should return an empty list. fixed now, I will also check the first script.

Comment: @Raphael ...also needed a fix. I probably didn't notice because the file came into existence during earlier tests. Both scripts should be fine now.

Comment: Thanks; it executes fine now. Now another problem: I've tried ALT+F7 (`begin-move`) and CTRL+ALT+L (`screensaver`) -- the former is blocked, the latter not. \*scratches head\* My version blocks both, with both using `gsettings` now.

Comment: @Raphael huh? both work fine here. Silly question, but are you sure you made no typo? Entry should be:  `["org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys", "screensaver"],`

Comment: @Raphael could you post the exact `keys =` section somewhere? I can see what happens then.

Comment: I copy-pasted your script, so...

Comment: Okay, wait. When I use the copied version, `screensaver` is blocked. If I add `begin-move`, `screensaver` is not blocked anymore. Could be a silly typo? ([`keys`](http://pastebin.com/SM2qiUxP))

Comment: @Raphael ??? I need to look into it, getting the same result as you, but see no typo? Need to look into it, will be back...

Comment: @Raphael aaargh, I fixed a few major stupidities in both scripts; indentation error(s), double for x in y .. must have been late. Both should be fixed now. –

Answer (score 7):

Based on [(an older version of) Jacob Vlijm's answer](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/863003/10)
 I wrote this version that solves these additional problems:

1. Honors changes the user makes while the script is running.
2. Does not reset values the user had set to the defaults.
3. Stores a backup of the settings in case the script quits while shortcuts are disabled.
4. <strike>Handles `gsettings` and `dconf` shortcuts.</strike> (This may have been a non-issue.)

**Open problems:**

- I can not find where some shortcuts such as <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> are set. These come from Unity resp. Compiz; [how can we programmatically change the shortcuts shown when you hold <kbd>Super</kbd>](https://askubuntu.com/q/867039/69674)?
- `xprop` does not reveal PIDs for all windows. Failing example: `stopwatch`. ([Jaco Vlijm has some ideas](https://askubuntu.com/a/863003/69674).)

---

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import os

# Path pattern to block
apppattern = "myprocess"

# Write a backup that can restore the settings at the
# start of the script.
# Leave empty to not write a backup.
backupfile = "~/.keymap_backup"

# Add the keys to be disabled below.
shortcuts = {
    "org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys/key" : "gsettings",
    "/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/key" : "dconf",
}

#
# Helper functions
#

# Run a command on the shell
def run(cmd):
    subprocess.Popen(cmd)

# Run a command on the shell and return the
# stripped result
def get(cmd):
    try:
        return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()
    except:
        pass

# Get the PID of the currently active window
def getactive():
    xdoid = get(["xdotool", "getactivewindow"])
    pidline = [l for l in get(["xprop", "-id", xdoid]).splitlines()\
                 if "_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL)" in l]
    if pidline:
        pid = pidline[0].split("=")[1].strip()
    else:
        # Something went wrong
        print("Warning: Could not obtain PID of current window")
        pid = ""

    return pid

def readkey(key):
    if shortcuts[key] == "gsettings":
        return get(["gsettings", "get"] + key.split("/"))
    elif shortcuts[key] == "dconf":
        return get(["dconf", "read", key])

def writekey(key, val):
    if val == "": 
        val = "['']"
    if shortcuts[key] == "gsettings":        
        run(["gsettings", "set"] + key.split("/") + [val])
    elif shortcuts[key] == "dconf":
        run(["dconf", "write", key, val])

def resetkey(key):
    if shortcuts[key] == "gsettings":
        run(["gsettings", "reset"] + key.split("/"))
    elif shortcuts[key] == "dconf":
        run(["dconf", "reset", key])

# If val == True, disables all shortcuts.
# If val == False, resets all shortcuts.
def setkeys(flag):
    for key, val in shortcutmap.items():
        if flag == True:
            # Read current value again; user may change
            # settings, after all!
            shortcutmap[key] = readkey(key)
            writekey(key, "")            
        elif flag == False:
            if val:
                writekey(key, val)
            else:
                resetkey(key)

#
# Main script
#

# Store current shortcuts in case they are non-default
# Note: if the default is set, dconf returns an empty string!
# Optionally, create a backup script to restore the value in case
# this script crashes at an inopportune time.
shortcutmap = {}
if backupfile:
    f = open(os.path.expanduser(backupfile),'w+') 
    f.write('#!/bin/sh\n')

for key, val in shortcuts.items():
    if shortcuts[key] == "gsettings":
        shortcutmap[key] = get(["gsettings", "get"] + key.split("/"))

        if backupfile:
            if shortcutmap[key]:
                f.write("gsettings set " + " ".join(key.split("/")) + " " + 
                shortcutmap[key] + "\n")
            else:
                f.write("gsettings reset " + " ".join(key.split("/")) + "\n")
    elif shortcuts[key] == "dconf":
        shortcutmap[key] = get(["dconf", "read", key])

        if backupfile:
            if shortcutmap[key]:
                f.write("dconf write " + key + " " + shortcutmap[key] + "\n")
            else:
                f.write("dconf reset " + key + "\n")

if backupfile: f.close()

# Check every half second if the window changed form or to a 
# matching application.
front1 = None
while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    checkpids = get(["pgrep", "-f", apppattern])

    if checkpids:
        checkpids = checkpids.splitlines()
        activepid = getactive()
        #print(activepid)

        if activepid:
            front2 = True if activepid in checkpids else False
        else:
            front2 = False
    else:
        front2 = False

    if front2 != front1:
        #print("Matches: " + str(flag))
        if front2:
            setkeys(True)
        else:
            setkeys(False)
    front1 = front2
```

**Notes:**

- Note the different key formats for `gsettings` resp. `dconf`.
- <strike>`gsettings` keys *do* appear in `dconf` but changes made there have no effect.
  As a general rule, add keys found using [Jacob's method](https://askubuntu.com/a/863003/69674) as `gsettings` and those you had to manually track down in `dconf` as such.</strike>
- Run the backup file as script in case the shortcuts get messed up, e.g. by the script terminating while shortcuts are disabled.

Comment: I collected some shortcuts useful for using JetBrains IDEs [here](https://gist.github.com/akerbos/5c9ff3ff5750ded36361d0323ac55fe6).

Comment: As mentioned before, `dconf` should not be used if `gsettings` is available, which is the case in all shortcuts you mention.  `gsettings` protects consistency of the `dconf` database. The issue was using "''" for *listed* values. fixed in the answer.

Comment: Regarding Jacob's comment, yes: all shortcuts I have tried (with my version of the script) work with `gsettings`. I'm leaving the code as is for now, but users may want to prefer the `gsettings` format.