# A shortcut to toggle keyboard shortcuts

Tags: shortcut-keys

Really the title says it all. I want to set a shortcut that will enable/disable (toggle) keyboard shortcuts. Is this even a possibility? It would be really useful for things like Blender where many shortcuts overlap, without having to permanently disable or change your system shortcuts.

Comment: are you referring to keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: A keyboard shortcut (ctrl alt f1) or some such, that would temporarily make all system shortcuts inactive, and then restore them when used again.

Comment: I believe what you are asking has already been answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/217310/606758). Unfortunately, the current title of the question does not indicate that it would be of much help.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/862957/block-unity-keyboard-shortcuts-when-a-certain-application-is-active/863003#863003

Comment: Post that as an answer and I'll accept it. It's a lot to look through, but I think I can use that script to make an empty shortcut file, and the default, then switch them with a shortcut. It looks complex, but doable.

Comment: Great! unfortunately, I will be hit on the head with a frying pan if I post that one here instead of marking this one as a dupe to that one :). Good question though. Please let me know if you run into problems.